# Output Cache generating OutOfMemoryException

Tags: asp.net, web-config, out-of-memory, outputcache

I'm getting OutOfMemoryException in my website when memory reaches 50% of total system memory. Investigating the memory I've found that my problem concern on the growing rates of Output Cache entries (Almost every page has it's own output cache varying by url parameters).

Searching on the web I saw some appointments about the  section at web.config, specially on the privateBytesLimit and percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit attributes, that deals with the threshold values to cache start flushing expired items and attempting to reclaim memory. But I din't understood if at this point the exceptions will be thrown too.

But I'm not sure about best and secure values to put at these attributes. Someone has informations about these values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/caching

Cheers.

Comment: I forgot to say: I'm using IIS 6.0 and this tag was introduced in IIS 7.0... Thanks!